# how to merge nginx config block when only little difference between rules

Tags: nginx

```
location /a/ {
  ----same
  ----same
  ----same
  ----same
  ----same
  rewrite /a/(.*) /$1 break; 
}

location /b/ {
  ----same
  ----same
  ----same
  ----same
  ----same
  deny ip...; 
}

location /c/ {
  ----same
  ----same
  ----same
  ----same
  ----same
  proxy_pass http://.....; 
}
```

I have a lot of location rules in my nginx.conf file, they are very similar.

how can i optimize them, remove the duplicated block ?

Comment: You can use separate files for all duplicate code and you can include those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file `same.conf` with below content

```
  ----same
  ----same
  ----same
  ----same
  ----same
```

Then change config as below

```
location /a/ {
  include <path to same.conf>;
  rewrite /a/(.*) /$1 break; 
}

location /b/ {
  include <path to same.conf>;
  deny ip...; 
}

location /c/ {
  include <path to same.conf>;
  proxy_pass http://.....; 
}
```